# c++: at what point should I start using "new char[N]" vs a static buffer "char[Nmax]"

Tags: c++

My question is with regard to C++

Suppose I write a function to return a list of items to the caller. Each item has 2 logical fields: 1) an int ID, and 2) some data whose size may vary, let's say from 4 bytes up to 16Kbytes. So my question is whether to use a data structure like:

```
struct item {
  int  field1;
  char field2[MAX_LEN];
```

OR, rather, to allocate field2 from the heap, and require the caller to destroy when he's done:

```
struct item{
  int  field1;
  char *field2;  // new char[N] -- destroy[] when done!
```

Since the max size of field #2 is large, is makes sense that this would be allocated from the heap, right? So once I know the size N, I call field2 = new char[N], and populate it.

Now, is this horribly inefficient?

Is it worse in cases where N is always small, i.e. suppose I have 10000 items that have N=4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should instead use one of the standard library containers, like `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`; then you don't have to worry about managing the memory yourself.

Comment: If the size is so variant, a container like vector is undoubtedly the way to go.

Comment: Truth. But it's also useful to remember `std::vector` allocates memory dynamically. Sometimes, in some rare, tight situations, this might be an issue. Then you can use `boost::array`, which is a convenient wrapper around primitive arrays, and is equally cheap.

Comment: Indeed -- KISS principle wins. This app is for a desktop PC, and there's no reason why I shouldn't use a vector<char> or a string. I initially was going this route, my concern was that it would be too expensive to create a new vector each time, if the vectors were only containing 4 bytes of data. My guess is -- yes, in a case where the are really just 4 bytes each time, then it's probably overkill to use a vector ... but any performance hit is probably not noticeable anyway, and the ability to cover the "large" cases without a hitch makes it well worth it to use a vector. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You could do both:

```
struct item {
    ...
    char *field2; // Points to buf if < 8 chars (assuming null-terminator).
    char buf[8];
};
```

This does require some clever copy semantics, so you'll need a custom copy-constructor and assignment operator.

Alternatively, if `item` is always heap-allocated, you could ensure that `item` and its data are always allocated together:

```
struct item {
    ...
    char field2[1];
}

item* new_item(int size) {
    int offset = &((item*)0)->field2[0] - (char*)0;
    return new(malloc(offset + size)) item;
}
```

Comment: use a union instead and save a couple of bytes (as you'll need a flag to say which storage is used).

Comment: A union is an option if space is at a premium, but it imposes a CPU cost on every single access.

Comment: what cost is there for a union at CPU time? AFAIK, the compiler just changes the offset.

Comment: The cost is in the fact that every time you want to access the data you have to test the flag to determine whether to treat the union as data or a pointer to the data. Without the union, you simply follow the pointer, regardless of whether the data is inlined or on the heap.

Comment: true, but that cost is made insignificant when you perform the required bounds-checking for this mechanism. .. ah! except when reading the value, I get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing that's horribly in efficient is all the time you will waste tracking down memory leaks. Use classes that take care of this for you.

But if you don't want to do that:

> suppose I have 10000 items that have N=4?

So you waste 40k of memory - your PC has at least a gigabyte, probably two, don't worry about it. A consistent interface, even if you're doing new/delete, is better than something fancy that will be harder to debug.

The only time when can safely use fixed-size buffers in production code is sizes are compile-time system constants, such as MAX_PATH.

Comment: Furthermore the only time I use char[] or char*, instead of using std::string which I generally prefer, is when I'm interfacing with O/S C-like APIs which expect char* parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends. As I see it:

**statically sized buffer**

Good

- No need to manage memory
- Very efficient in terms of execution speed

Bad

- Might waste some memory

**dynamically sized buffer**

Good

- Does not have to waste any memory, as the exact amount needed is known

Bad

- Memory must be managed.
- Might be slow(er)

---

With that in mind, and based on the situation (Is it likely sizes will vary much? Is execution speed extra important? ... ), pick one.